# 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'- as.numeric() in R

Tags: r, dataframe, numeric

Like in the `iris` dataset, in my data all columns are classified as numeric, but the whole data.frame is not classified as numeric. The following code shows what I tried.
I want `iris` to be numeric without changes in the form of the data

```
data("iris")
> is.numeric(iris)
[1] FALSE
iris <- as.numeric(iris)
ERROR: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

> iris <- lapply(iris, as.numeric)
> is.numeric(iris)
[1] FALSE

> iris <- as.numeric(unlist(iris))
> is.numeric(iris)
[1] TRUE ##but now it is only one column (instead of 5)
```

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve here, but maybe `data.matrix(iris)` is what you are looking for.

Comment: The Species column of iris is a factor. In the last part, you are coercing the factor column to a numeric, hence it works.. not very sure what you are trying to do here

Comment: `iris` is a `data.frame`, and therefore never a `numeric`. Even if you make all of its columns into `numeric`s (but see StupidWolf’s caveat), this doesn’t make the table *itself* `numeric`.

Comment: OMG! @KonradRudolph, I did not know that. Like @nicola suggested, it works with ``` data.matrix(iris)``` .  ;)

Answer (score 0):

`numeric` is a data type description which is only valid for vectors and matrices.  Data frames are by definition lists. There is no reason to want the dataframe to be a numeric if all of the columns within it are numeric.